# How can I make position of arrow be fixed in the box during the resizing?

Tags: html, css

This is my code for a responsive box. I can't make the position of arrow be fixed in the box during the resizing. Can you help me about where is the problem? and whether there is a better way from to use images?

I want to do something like that:

[image]

```css
.boxes {
width: 80%;
border: 1px solid #dfe8f1;
border-radius: 3px;
margin: 2% auto;
padding: 15px;
height: 25%;
position: relative;
}

.arrow-box {
width: 11px;
height: 20px;
margin: -39px 0 0 -25px;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">                                    
<div class="blue-header">appointment</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dones odio.</p>
<img src="./images/arrow-for-box.jpg" class="arrow-box">
<div class="footer">
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/sABFEdWNreQABAAQAAABkAAD/4QMsaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wLwA8P3hwYWNrZXQgYmVnaW49Iu+7vyIgaWQ9Ilc1TTBNcENlaGlIenJlU3pOVGN6a2M5ZCI/PiA8eDp4bXBtZXRhIHhtbG5zOng9ImFkb2JlOm5zOm1ldGEvIiB4OnhtcHRrPSJBZG9iZSBYTVAgQ29yZSA1LjYtYzE0OCA3OS4xNjQwMzYsIDIwMTkvMDgvMTMtMDE6MDY6NTcgICAgICAgICI+IDxyZGY6UkRGIHhtbG5zOnJkZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS8wMi8yMi1yZGYtc3ludGF4LW5zIyI+IDxyZGY6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24gcmRmOmFib3V0PSIiIHhtbG5zOnhtcD0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wLyIgeG1sbnM6eG1wTU09Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9tbS8iIHhtbG5zOnN0UmVmPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvc1R5cGUvUmVzb3VyY2VSZWYjIiB4bXA6Q3JlYXRvclRvb2w9IkFkb2JlIFBob3Rvc2hvcCAyMS4wIChXaW5kb3dzKSIgeG1wTU06SW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDo1QzBDMURGQjE3RkMxMUVBOTY4Q0IxRjQ0MTdBQzM5RiIgeG1wTU06RG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDo1QzBDMURGQzE3RkMxMUVBOTY4Q0IxRjQ0MTdBQzM5RiI+IDx4bXBNTTpEZXJpdmVkRnJvbSBzdFJlZjppbnN0YW5jZUlEPSJ4bXAuaWlkOjVDMEMxREY5MTdGQzExRUE5NjhDQjFGNDQxN0FDMzlGIiBzdFJlZjpkb2N1bWVudElEPSJ4bXAuZGlkOjVDMEMxREZBMTdGQzExRUE5NjhDQjFGNDQxN0FDMzlGIi8+IDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPiA8L3JkZjpSREY+IDwveDp4bXBtZXRhPiA8P3hwYWNrZXQgZW5kPSJyIj8+/+4ADkFkb2JlAGTAAAAAAf/bAIQAAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQICAgICAgICAgICAwMDAwMDAwMDAwEBAQEBAQECAQECAgIBAgIDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMD/8AAEQgAFAALAwERAAIRAQMRAf/EAHQAAAMBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQFBwoBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAhAAAAMGBQAIBwAAAAAAAAAAAgMEARITFAUVABEiBhYhMUFCI2NklCU1RYUmF0cRAAIBBAMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARAfAhMaFBsSL/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AN5tYrCw1Zx3bsIytmFANWrTQRkO20JzzAL14GCCw9aewIpRI8ER4gtEJoSQjGwAbhCGBL3bcEOTh/MQRLvcLnyiPLRuQTfeeloXhQYWjFc4dqkijKvUAdG/Dlo6HUtaGtVRSrpO4zOk1fUqga0wVJ3Ce36x1Foz25FqiAAJYwBpYAmwpQMAKa7Z7PUeQStllTLjO5S8vlqf7Xs8nHdb+TurLAEt+OSX9AmbP5sxxLkHsv2BafuUr6rGvK5a2+lsz6fCel29H//Z
" alt="clock">
    <i>a few seconds ago</i>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I did my best to make my question transparent, I also included links to the question and I don't think it's unclear partial of that!

Comment: It's very unclear bro. You saying does not move. In my Fiddle copied from you the arrow does not move and is like same as your example ..

Comment: @jary, See also the picture please. What I expect is the result of the code there!

Comment: See edited answer, i've pasted the wrong code..

Comment: Serious what is different from my code except the yellow topline and clock image from this picture you are added on top of this question https://i.ibb.co/Q9x43YX/agileui-com-demo-monarch-demo-admin-template-index-10.jpg vs my fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/srv6qe9b/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a jsfiddle with what I think you are asking:
https://jsfiddle.net/kLnh6vsm/

I added the following code:

```css
.arrow {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #dfe8f1;
  border-top: 1px solid #dfe8f1;
  position: absolute;
  left: -12px;
  top: 45%;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

And removed the image.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you want, but i prefer native css instead of using images.
But is this the desired result?

```
.footer img{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -22px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  height: 13px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/srv6qe9b/

Comment: I'm coding a project that I should not use to any library, and instead of icons I used images in this!
there is what I was expecting into the picture!
Your answer doesn't work in code either, but thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Serious what is different from my code except the yellow topline and clock image from this picture you are added on top of this question https://i.ibb.co/Q9x43YX/agileui-com-demo-monarch-demo-admin-template-index-10.jpg vs my fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/srv6qe9b/

Comment: When you change the page width, the arrow moves! I don't want this to happen!

Comment: Would be great for others to first be clear of what you want. Like explain in what cases things are breaking the layout. It's the very common on what i wrote, except for the top position what will stay the same on resizing.. Not cool bro..

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS change .arrow-box with img and it should be fine.